# Can "bind -x" access the current command line?

Tags: bash, readline

When I type some command, I sometimes want to read the help of the command. For example, when I'm typing

```
sort --overwrite some_texI # I is a cursor
```

, I'd like to check if `sort` command has `--overwrite` option, reading the output of `sort --help` or whatever option-summary I've made. I expect `bind -x` could realize this, but have no idea how to pass (a part of) the current command line information (in this case, the word "sort"). Of course, `bind -x 'KEY: "sort --help"'` works well, but I want this to work for all commands. So the pseudo command would be `bind -x 'KEY: "CURRENT_COMMAND --help"'`.

Could anyone please give a solution or a hint?

Comment: @kvantour Probably that is not I want. I'm already using the programmable completion, and it is convenient, but it doesn't tell me, for example, the meaning of the option. As the title of my post indicates, I would like to execute arbitrary commands which use the information of the current command line. Not only `sort --help` but also `print_help_summary_created_by_me sort` etc.

Comment: A part of your question reads _I'd like to check if sort command has --overwrite option_. The usage of a good `bash-autocompletion` would allow you to quickly check if this option is available. It might not tell you what the option exactly does.

Comment: I just checked the autocompletion in ZSH (another shell derived from bash), and there the autocompletion even mentions what the option is about.

Comment: While on the topic of ZSH, you can use ESC-q to push the current command on to the buffer stack, giving you a fresh command line on which to run `sort --help`. When that exits, `sort --overwrite some_tex` would be popped off the stack and put back on the command line.

Comment: `zsh` isn't really derived from `bash`. They both share a common ancestor in the Bourne shell, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `READLINE_LINE` variable of bash. `man bash` says

> `bind` [-m keymap] keyseq:readline-command
>
> (snip)
>
> `-x` keyseq:shell-command
>
> (snip) When shell-command is executed, the shell sets the `READLINE_LINE` variable to the contents of the readline line buffer

So what you want is the first word of `READLINE_LINE`. Thus, the solution is `bind -x 'KEY": "array=($READLINE_LINE); ${array[0]} --help"'`.